# COMport.Readline() Issues : Flooded buffer and string manipulation

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, buffer, readline

I have a weight scale that has constant output to a serial port. I made an application that loops every 3 seconds to read the newest weight on the scale, the loop uses a `Async` Sub and then a `Await Task.Run(Sub()` then sleeps for 3 seconds. I am having 2 issues.

First, The buffer is flooding with data and therefore if you take weight off, say 100 lb, it still reads the old data in the buffer meanwhile the actual weight on the scale is 0. But it slowly goes down every 3 secs. I tried to loop the `readline()` continuously in a Backgroundworker but the scale still outputs to fast. Should I try 'DiscardBuffer()' before `readline()`? Or is there another reading method?

Code: COM Port Props

```
    With COMScale 'COM Port Properties

        .PortName = cmbPorts.Text 'COM Port Name

        .Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None

        .DataBits = 8

        .StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One

        .BaudRate = 9600

        .ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1

        .NewLine = vbCr

        .ReadTimeout = 5000

    End With
```

Code: Backgroundworker

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    WeightA = 0

    COMScale.DiscardInBuffer()

    Try

        COMScale.ReadTimeout = 10000

        Do

            Dim Incoming As String = COMScale.ReadLine()

            If Incoming Is Nothing Then

                Exit Do

            Else

                WeightA &= Incoming

            End If

        Loop

    Catch ex As TimeoutException

        WeightA = "N/A"

        MsgBox(COMScale.PortName & "Timed Out")

    Finally

        'If com1 IsNot Nothing Then com1.Close()

        lblWeightA.Text = WeightA

    End Try

End Sub
```

Second issue is the string the scale outputs, it likes like this...

"5?" & ChrW(2) & ChrW(2) & "??j" & ChrW(2) & ";     47" & ChrW(2) & ChrW(2) & ChrW(2) & ChrW(2) & "??j" & ChrW(2) & ";     475" & ChrW(2) & ChrW(2) & ChrW(2) & "??j" & ChrW(2) & ";     475    00"

On the scale it says 47.5 lbs

All I need is the "475" numbers at the end but with a decimal so the string is 47.5 . The only thing I can think of is `Right(string)` issue I see with using `Right(String)` is that it could be 1000 lbs, 100 lbs or 10 lbs, so it would cut off what I need. Whats my best option here?

Comment: Does the reading have a carriage return <CR> or line feed <LF> after each read?  You need to build a string until you get the whole message then use it.  The datarecieved event fires somewhat randomly and you will only get parts of the whole string sometimes.  You need to key off a char to know when the stream is done, then use it.  I generally use callback functions or [delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172879.aspx).  With most things a <CR><LF> means the end of the stream, and I key off that then fire my delegate function to process the response.

Comment: For the second part, do a string `Split` on the char `;`.  It will split the string into a string array for each semi-colon then you can parse the last record for the 47500.  Read the manual on the scale, but you should just be able to parse that value and divide by 1000.

Comment: I was using `newline = vbCr` is that what you mean? Im new to using serial ports. If i dont use it there is no displayed data.

Comment: The serial port class should have an event for datarecieved.  It fires whenever data is received on that serial port.  Generally you want to use that event for reading the data.  Problem is, it can fire multiple times, so it might take multiple events to get the whole data string, that's why you need to build a string and when you see a character that signifies you got the whole thing, you can then parse that string, clear it and do it each time you get the whole response.  I'm not too familiar with vb, but I do all this in C# and it should be similar.

Comment: Can you name the methods for this? That way i can figure out how to do this. As far as building the string through multiple events not the datarecieved.

Comment: Hi @holi4683, please see [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx).  For building the string, I use a string builder.  In the data recieved event you can just do `string data = serialport1.readExisting();` to get the string from the event, then I would go through each char in the string.  If it doesn't match the char you are looking for (in most cases a CR), then add it to your stringbuilder, otherwise you know you have the whole string and parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sleeping for 3 seconds your application should read continuously. Then the buffer won't fill up.

So have your BackgroundWorker just run in a loop. Also don't modify any UI element from your background worker. Instead use ReportProgress to send it to the form.

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    COMScale.DiscardInBuffer()
    Dim buffer As String
    While e.Cancel = False

        Try

            buffer &= COMScale.ReadLine()

            buffer = ProcessBuffer(buffer)

        Catch ex As TimeoutException
            BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, ex)
        End Try

    End While
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    If TypeOf e.UserState Is TimeoutException Then
        lblWeightA.Text = "N/A"
        MessageBox.Show("Timeout")
    ElseIf TypeOf e.UserState Is Decimal Then
        lblWeightA.Text = CDec(e.UserState).ToString()
    End If
End Sub

Private Function ProcessBuffer(inputBuffer As String)
    'Parse your string. Looking for the last occurrence of the data you need.

    If extractedPortion IsNot Nothing 
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, Decimal.Parse(extractedPortion))
    End If

    Return leftOverChacters
End Function
```

Comment: Oh and the reason I was waiting 3 secs is because I needed to allow the weight to settle after the weight changes, I am not using it any more because of logic issues.

Comment: I got it to work between your code and msdn. Im using, from an example, `Me . BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync (2000)` to start the back ground thread. Do you know what the 2000 means?

Comment: You can pass any value to `RunWorkerAsync` and it will be available in the `DoWork` handler as `e.Argument`. In this case you're not using it for anything so don't bother passing it. My guess is they were using it as a timeout wherever you copied that from

Comment: Ok, i tried to just leave it as `Me.BackgroundWorker1.Ru‌​nWorkerAsync ()` but apparently its an integer for a thread sleep. Im just going to leave it in because it doesn't affect my process. Thanks for your help!